# Accessing ParentForm from child and ensuring the child is added

Tags: c#, winforms, events, user-controls

I have code that dynamically loads (and destroys) user controls of different types onto a form as they are needed. The user control uses properties from its parent to load certain values into controls such as textboxes and check boxes. The issue is that in the line:

```
activeControl = new userControl1(params...);
```

my constructor is obviously going to try loading fields that don't exist yet (they belong to the parent form) since it hasn't been added to the parent form until after userControl1 is created.

I tried solving this using the ParentChanged event of the user control so it waits until its parent is set before loading fields. The problem here is when I destroy userControl1 and create a userControl2, the parent changes and it tries to load the fields from the null ParentForm (the exact problem I had originally.

Is there a preferred way to tackle this? Clearly, I could just add something like

```
if(this.ParentForm == null) { return; }
```

to the ParentChanged event or something along those lines. But this feels neither elegant nor safe. Am I overlooking some event or preferred way to accomplish this?

Comment: often in events a check for null is a good idea (not bad idea).  During the InitializeComponent() events get triggered and have to be ignored.  Row index of listboxes and comboboxes during these false event are -1 and checking for index >= 0 is normal in events handlers.

Comment: What actually you're accessing from `ParentForm`? It isn't a good idea to access parent form inside the user control in general, if you're casting the `ParentForm` to some other sub type.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not necessarily bad to check for `null` references and divert the code accordingly (e.g. not try to reference a missing object), the better approach here is to decouple your `UserControl` classes from their parents.

That is, these `UserControl` classes should not have any awareness of their parent form types at all. To do otherwise is to negate one of the major benefits of OOP: code reuse. With your current design, even if you get it to work without crashing, you can't ever use these `UserControl` objects except in the context of this specific parent form type.

You may think today that that's okay, that you'll never want to use them in any other context. But the future is hard to predict. You may decide, for example, that you want a variation on the parent form that should still use these same `UserControl` objects.

What you should be doing is exposing the `UserControl` state via public properties, and then allow the parent form to initialize those as necessary.

Here's a very simple example (I'm omitting the Designer-created code…I assume that you can infer from the field names what I mean):

```
partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    /* ... */

    public bool IsMyFlagChecked
    {
        get { return checkBox1.Checked; }
        set { checkBox1.Checked = value; }
    }

    /* ... */
}

partial class ParentForm : Form
{
    /* ... */

    private void SomeMethodThatAddsUserControl1()
    {
        UserControl1 uc1 = new UserControl1;

        uc1.IsMyFlagChecked =
            this.SomeParentFormPropertyUserControl1UsedToReferenceDirectly;
        // other initialization for uc1...

        Controls.Add(uc1);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

(Note that without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates your question, I can't provide a more detailed code example than the above. If this doesn't seem to address your question, please edit it so that it provides more detail, including a better code example).